# fail to set timeoutInterval when using subclass of AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

I made a subclass of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` and wanted to set timeout to 3 seconds.

```
[netMgr.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:3.f];
```

But it doesn't work.

I can figure out that it's because the auto key value observing returns `NO` in `automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey` when the key is `timeoutInterval`

Could anyone tell me the reason, or What's the right way to set timeout of request ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree. Twenty-one days ago, the commit [0f3829f](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/0f3829f6afdfa57eced1e80c317e68ca5e5f85d0) turned off automatic notification for these properties. It's the observer for these properties that ensures that any request serializer property changes translate to modification of the `NSMutableURLRequest` object for requests issued via `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`.

I have to assume mattt had a reason for turning off this notification (looks like it is in response to issue [#2523](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2523), which should probably be reconsidered), so until this is remedied, I'd suggest one merely manually posting the notification.

```
[manager.requestSerializer willChangeValueForKey:@"timeoutInterval"];
manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = ...;
[manager.requestSerializer didChangeValueForKey:@"timeoutInterval"];
```

---

Note, this was fixed 26 March 2015 in commit [7d8e286](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/7d8e2867e026c303c12b82896b734fb39ed60d9e).